# How to fit an image inside a table with 100% height?

Tags: html, css, image, css-tables

I can't manage to get the image to fit 100% to the height of a css made table. As you see below, the table and image is totally ignoring the parent element's dimensions.

Everything needs to be dynamically that's why I work with percent.

```css
.img {
  max-width: 50%;
  height: 100px; // <-- This should be able to be dynamic ( anything )
}

.img .table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.img .row {
  display: table-row;
}

.img .cell {
  display: table-cell;
}

.img .row.img-el,
.img .row.img-el .cell {
  height: 100%;
}

.img img {
  max-width: auto;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="img pull-left gap-right bigger">
  <div class="table">
    <div class="row img-el">
      <div class="cell"><img src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-9QM7ciGXRkQ/V1hsB-wNLBI/AAAAAAAAMoA/eYbSHs00PTAjrI4QAmvYAIGCUe1AuRAnwCLcB/s1600/bryan_cranston_0095.jpg" style="height:100%;float:left" /></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell img-text">Hello</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Expected result:**

[image]

**Update:** Is it possible to fix it with flex in any way?

Comment: Do you have an image with the expected result? I am not sure to understand what you are trying to do...

Comment: @Badacadabra have updated the post

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?

```css
.img {
  max-width: 50%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.img .table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.img .row {
  display: table-row;
}

.img .cell {
  display: table-cell;
}

.img .row.img-el,
.img .row.img-el .cell {
  height: 100%;
}

.img img {
  max-width: auto;
  height: 100%;
}

.cell img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="img pull-left gap-right bigger">
  <div class="table">
    <div class="row img-el">
      <div class="cell"><img src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-9QM7ciGXRkQ/V1hsB-wNLBI/AAAAAAAAMoA/eYbSHs00PTAjrI4QAmvYAIGCUe1AuRAnwCLcB/s1600/bryan_cranston_0095.jpg" style="float:left" /></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell img-text">Hello</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is that that require a free height. If the `.img` element is for example 100px height. The table and image is going over. :/

Answer (score -1):

you have to give it a specific height like 200px it cant take a height of 100% of nothing. If you had a box with the height of 200px; you can make the image height be 100% which is 200px